# Add margin between a RadioButton and its label in Android?

Tags: android, radio-button

Is it possible to add a little bit of space between a RadioButton and the label while still using Android's built-in components? By default the text looks a little scrunched.

```
<RadioButton android:id="@+id/rb1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Text"/>
```

I've tried a couple of things:

1. Specifying margin and padding seem to add space around the entire element (button and text, together). That makes sense, but doesn't do what I need.
2. Creating a custom drawable via XML specifying images for the checked and unchecked states, then adding a few extra pixels to the right side of each image. This should work, but now you are stepping outside the default UI. (Not the end of the world, but not ideal)
3. Add extra whitespace to the beginning of each label. Android seems to trim a leading space character, as in " My String", but specifying unicode U+00A0, as in "\u00A0My String" does the trick. This works, but it seems kinda dirty.

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 138):

For anyone reading this now, the accepted answer will lead to some layout problems on newer APIs causing too much padding.

On API <= 16 you can set `paddingLeft` on the radio button to set the padding relative to the radio button's view bounds.  Additionally, a patch nine background also changes the view bounds relative to the view.

On API >= 17 the `paddingLeft` (or `paddingStart`) is in relation to the radio button drawable.  Same applies to the about a patch nine. To better illustrate padding differences see the attached screenshot.

If you dig through the code you will find a new method in API 17 called [getHorizontalOffsetForDrawables](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/widget/CompoundButton.java#CompoundButton.getHorizontalOffsetForDrawables%28%29).  This method is called when calculating the left padding for a radio button(hence the additional space illustrated in the picture).

TL;DR Just use `paddingLeft` if your `minSdkVersion` is >= 17. If you support API <= 16, you should have radio button style for the min SDK you are supporting and another style for API 17+.

[image: combine screenshots showing left padding differences between API versions]

Comment: api 17 is android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1

Comment: The best way to do this is with a "values-v17" directory; put your API 17+ dimension in a resources xml there and the standard one for 16 and below in just plain "values".

Comment: Amazing how Google developers / management are treating us usual devs. They do whatever they want, whenever they want. Consistency and integrity mean nothing to them.

Comment: Is there also a way to set a padding left to the radiobutton drawable? So how to set a padding between the left side of the sceen and the radiobutton drawable (NOT THE ENTIRE RADIOBUTTON).

Answer (score 71):

Not sure if this will fix your problem, but have you tried Radio Button's "Padding left" property with a value of 50dip or more

Comment: This works, and 50dip is needed to cover the width of the default drawable.  At first I used 20dip and the text moved left!  That's because the anchoring point is not the right edge of the drawable; it is the left edge of the drawable.

Answer (score 59):

i tried several ways and finished with this one working correctly on both emulator and devices:

```
    <RadioButton
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_own_selector"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/your_spacing" />
```

- **android:background** needs to be transparent as it seems on api10 there is a background with intrinsic paddings (not tried with other apis but the solution works on others too)
- **android:button** needs to be *null* as paddings will not work correctly otherwise
- **android:drawableLeft** needs to be specified instead of *android:button*
- **android:drawablePadding** is the space that will be between your drawable and your text

Comment: The best answer! You can also set android:background="@null" and will look as you stated with no padding.

Comment: when i'm setting android:button="@null" , the radio button is not getting checked(clicked). Im i doing something wrong. please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052820/android-custom-radio-button-not-getting-checked

Comment: @Shirish this solution has nothing to do with your button not being clicked. I just implemented it and it is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 34):

Add **margin** between a **radiobutton** its **label** by **paddingLeft**:

```
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
```

Just set your custom **padding**.

RadioButton's xml property.

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radHighest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/YourImageResource"
    android:drawablePadding="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:text="@string/txt_my_text"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

**Done**

Answer (score 27):

Use the following XML attributes. It worked for me

For API <= 16 use

```
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
```

For API >= 17 use

```
android:paddingStart="@16dp"
```

Eg:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/popularityRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/radio_button_text"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/radio_button_text"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/radio_button_text"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/radio_button_text"
        android:text="Popularity"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sort_dialog_text_size"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.RadioButton" />
```

[image]

Further More: `drawablePadding` attribute doesn't work. It only works if you added a drawable in your radio button. For Eg:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableEnd="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:drawablePadding="56dp"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
    android:text="New RadioButton" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Can't try this right now to verify, but have you tried to see if the attribute [android:drawablePadding](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawablePadding) does what you need?

Comment: Hm. Gave it a try and it doesn't seem to have any effect in this situation. Thanks for the suggestion, it certainly sounds right from the description: "The padding between the drawables and the text".

Answer (score 4):

```
final float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
checkBox.setPadding(checkBox.getPaddingLeft() + (int)(10.0f * scale + 0.5f),

    checkBox.getPaddingTop(),
    checkBox.getPaddingRight(),
    checkBox.getPaddingBottom());
```

Answer (score 1):

The padding between the drawables and the text. It will be achieved by adding line below in xml file.
   `android:drawablePadding="@dimen/10dp"`

Comment: i was looking exactly for this... helped me a lot

Comment: `@dimen/10dp` bad practise

Answer (score 1):

jusst use padding start for API above 16

Answer (score 0):

I have tried, "android:paddingLeft" will works. paddingLeft will only impact the text while keep the radio image stay at the original position.

Answer (score -1):

The "android:paddingLeft" only seems to work correctly under android 4.2.2

i have tried almost all versions of android and it only works on the 4.2.2 version.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using different approach that I think should work on all API versions.
Instead of applying padding I'm adding an empty view between to RadioButtons:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp" />
```

This should give you 20dp padding.

Answer (score -1):

I came here looking for an answer and the simplest way (after some thinking) was add spacing at the beginning of the label itself like so

```
<RadioGroup
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnChangeMode"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
     android:layout_below="@+id/view3"
     android:gravity="center|left"
     android:id="@+id/ledRadioGroup">
<RadioButton
         android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=" On"
         android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
         android:id="@+id/ledon"
         android:textColor="@color/white" />
<RadioButton
         android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text=" Off"
         android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
         android:id="@+id/ledoff"
         android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score -1):

for me works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="true">
            <layer-list>
                <item android:right="5dp">
                    <shape android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:shape="oval">
                     <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
                     <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:state_checked="false">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:right="5dp">
            <shape android:paddingLeft="5dp" android:shape="oval">
                <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
                <solid android:color="@color/grey" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/text2"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Consider adding some comments to explain how this solve the problem ;)

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the gravity attribute of radio button .

```
<RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_all"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/padding_30dp"
                        android:text="@string/filter_inv_all"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_18" />
```

This will align the text to the right most end . Check out the first radio  in the image.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can this code on your XML file

```
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/rButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawablePadding="50dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:text="@string/your_text" />
```

or use this on Activity class

```
radioButton.setPadding(12, 10, 0, 10);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a style in style.xml like this

```
<style name="Button.Radio">

    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/spacing_large</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Put that style in radio button

```
 <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_guest_busy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:text="@string/guest_is_waiting"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_3x_medium"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing_large"
                android:textColor="@color/color_text_heading_dark"
                style="@style/Button.Radio"/>
```

You can change any attribute same as button as it RadioButton indirectly inherits button.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is an old question, but with this solution, I finally got peace of mind and forget about API level.

Left side vertical RadioGroup with right side vertical text view.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Radio 1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Radio 2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Mark Buikema, Absolutely it is not label, but it does works like label here! If you want click labels, you can add click listeners to TextViews. My point is, does we need to implement layout for e-v-e-r-y version of android os? I think, no.