# Is it possible to control radio button label to appear at extreme right?

Tags: android, radio-button

[image]I am making my activity in such a way that radio button is at extreme left and its label is at extreme right.I can use a text view beside each radio button to look like that without any label of radio button.But is it possible to break its label and make it to appear at right?

Comment: you mean first lable and then radio button like ?

Comment: Ok....:(....Any customized way.......?

Comment: Thats cool .......I may proceed.....

Comment: well wait for some more answers, you might get help from more experienced person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to  the given answers.I found the answer myself.I have to use only one attribute in the xml file where radio button is described

```
android:gravity="center|right"
```

Comment: Excellent. Didn't know this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can try alternet way by a table with 2 column , in one put radio button without text and in another put TextView with the text you want :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the answer is no.

You could however specify the `android:paddingLeft` to put some space between the radio button and it's label.

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134591/add-margin-between-a-radiobutton-its-label-in-android), it needs to be a value of 50dip or more, as the padding is measured from the left edge of the radio button drawable.