# Text leftside of a RadioButton with a margin on Android

Tags: android, layout, textview, radio-button

I want to have the "label", - the text you set in your `RadioButton` to show left of the button and have some padding in between.

Adding an additional `TextView` into the layout doesn't work because my `RadioGroup` does not work (i can choose multiple buttons) if i add anything other then a `RadioButton` into the `RadioGroup`.

So, how can i change the RadioButton to be `<text><buttondrawable>` instead of `<buttondrawable><text>`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting `android:button="@null"` and adding the drawable of the `RadioButton` as `android:drawableRight`. You can change the Padding between the text and the drawable with `android:drawablePadding` .

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radios"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/first"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/second"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Having two of those inside of a RadioGroup, I can still select both.

Comment: Thanks! Very clever solution and i can easily add the padding i wanted with `android:drawablePadding`.

Comment: The TextView still reserves space for the Button on the left, but when you set a negative margin/padding on the left, you can clean that up.

Comment: regarding my previous comment, the space is not reserved on JellyBean So you have to make another Version without the negative Padding for JellyBean Devices.

Comment: Setting `android:background="@null"` on the `RadioButton` will remove the mysterious padding.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above makes the image have no selected state.

May this help you:

- On API <= 16 you can set padding left on the radio button to set the padding relative to the radio button's view bounds. Additionally a patch nine background also changes the view bounds relative to the view.
- On API 17 the left padding is in relation to the radio button drawable. Same applies to the about a patch nine. To better illustrate padding differences see the attached screen shot.

If you dig through the code you will find a new method in api 17 called getHorizontalOffsetForDrawables. This method is called when calculating the left padding for a radio button(hence the additional space illustrated in the picture).

TL;DR You should have radio button style for the min sdk you are supporting and another style for api 17+

the answer is from [this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134591/add-margin-between-a-radiobutton-its-label-in-android) answered by @James Baca

Comment: Please add the essence in a code snippet, future readers should not have to follow your link, unless they want more in-depth information.

Comment: Also, the order of answers may vary, so better refer to an answer by the poster's name.

Answer (score 0):

you can also change layout direction right to left and align text to start

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textAlignment="textStart"
```

Answer (score 0):

step1-create drawable radio_button_insert.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:drawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_check_circle_24"
    android:insetRight="@dimen/dp10">
</inset>
```

step2-create drawable custom_radio_button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_inset" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

step3-create drawable for background.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_roundcorner_blue_border" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_roundcorner_gray_border" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

step 4- use in radio button layout.

```
 <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rg_options"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp10"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_store"
                    android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_radio_background"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp25"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_radio_background"
                    android:button="@drawable/custom_radio_button"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_your_manufacturers"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </RadioGroup>
```

Output:[image: Radio button and background shape]