# Android RadioButton issue when setting label on the left

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I want my radiobutton label the be on the left side of the button.

Thanks to this answer, I managed to achieve this objective :

[Text leftside of a RadioButton with a margin on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567950/text-leftside-of-a-radiobutton-with-a-margin-on-android)

But I have a weird issue my radiobutton looks like this :

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/29/1437064344-capture-d-ecran-2015-07-16-a-18-27-37.png

And following my app style (material), it should looks like this, and it does when I don't use android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio" :

http://www.noelshack.com/2015-29-1437064410-capture-d-ecran-2015-07-16-a-18-28-20.png

Here is the code I use to put the text on the left side :

```
 <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/book_for_radiobtn_later"
                    android:button="@null"
                    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
                    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                    style="@style/Custom_text_black"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/later"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/material_text_body1" />
```

Do you have any idea why my button looks weird when I use the drawableRight attribute ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
android:drawablePadding="20dp"
```

As per my thinking you should remove padding line.Hope it is works for for you.