# How to center the text in customized Radio Buttons in Android

Tags: android, radio-button, text-alignment

I am using some customized RadioButtons in Android. Unfortunately the text can't be aligned in the center altough I set the gravity and textAlignment attributes to "center". You can see in my screenshot that the text is more on the right side:

[image]

Here you see the code:
Radio Button in the constraintLayout:

```
  <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/r_Button_Small"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_73sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_28sdp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:text="@string/small"
        android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.322"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_50sdp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.584"
         />
```

Background files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/state_checked" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/state_unchecked" />

</selector>
```

with state file "checked"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorBlue">
    </solid>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/_25sdp"></corners>
</shape>
```

and "state uncheched"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorTest">
    </solid>
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/_25sdp"></corners>
</shape>
```

If you are wondering what "@dimen/_25sdp" is: It is scalable size unit from https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Do you know how I can align the text into the center? I'appreciate every comment and would be thankful for your help.

Comment: check out the attribute `android:drawablePadding=""`. I think that might help.

Comment: Watch [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134591/add-margin-between-a-radiobutton-and-its-label-in-android) for full explanation.

Comment: Thanks Suvajit for your answer. Which value do I have to specify for that attribute?

Comment: just hardcode it and check what fits for you. Give them in `sp`s.

Comment: Another thing you can do which is little bit messy. You can make a `LinearLayout`, which has 2 children one is a `RadioButton` without any label and another is a `TextView`. Now the `TextView` can be in the middle.

Comment: Basically you have add paddingEnd to `RadioButton` exactly to the size of circle . I think a better workaround for it to create a Custom `ViewGroup` and make it act like `RadioButton`just mentioned in comment above. This will work if There is no `RadioGroup` .

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will try to use the hard coding approach

Answer (score 0):

change your gravity with center to fill and remove text alignment

```
android:gravity="fill"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tushar. If I use your solutions the vertical alignment gets incorrect. The text is then not aligned to the circle of the RadioButton which does not look good